# Too large predictions MLPRegressor

Tags: python, neural-network, predict

I am trying to predict values using `MLPRegressor` from `scikit-learn` in Python, but the predictions I get are in the thousands while they should be 0.0-ish (positive and negative percentages). 
I want to use `'adam'`, `'relu'` and have three layers of 32, 16 and 8 neurons respectively, because I am mimicking a data experiment. My train set currently consists of 163 data points from 855 variables.

The code I am using:

```
mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(32,16,8), activation='relu', solver='adam')
arr_train_Y = np.ravel(arr_train_Y)
mlp.fit(arr_train_X, arr_train_Y)
y_pred_NN = mlp.predict(arr_test_X)
```

Why are my predictions so high and how do I get them to be more accurate?

Comment: Is it possible your training and test data aren't even? _(One is normalized and the other isn't?)_